# Define a function which function name is masked by a macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, masking

Sometimes, it can be handy to mask a function by a macro of same name.
In this contrived example, the macros makes it possible to insert additional verification while calling `function()`.

```
int function(int i);

#define function(i)  ( assert(i>0), function(i) )
```

Other more common usages make the macro translate into faster code, like a direct table entry point, for improved performance.
In all cases, the goal is to preserve the symbol of same name in the library, to ensure it exists and can be invoked from the library by another program without requiring the `*.h` (typically from a wrapper in a language different from `C`).

In the corresponding unit, defining `function()` now has a problem : `function` is now a macros. So `int function(int i) { ... }` will be expanded, and fail pretty badly.

The solution to this problem is simple : just `#undef function` before the definition, and then implement the function.

All is fine, except that ...

If, in a later section of the same unit, another function invokes `function()`, it will now invoke the symbol directly, instead of the macro in the `*.h`, thus losing the extra-functionalities provided by the macros, which might be undesirable.

Another work-around to this issue is available in `gcc`, using compiler extension `#pragma push_macro`.
It works, but is pretty much ugly, adding a minimum of 3 lines around the function definition, which doesn't help for readability. And this is without counting portability shenanigans, which will add more complexity.

Yet, masking a function with a macro of same name isn't new. I'm pretty sure I've read books suggesting this design as far back as C90 standard libraries.

I'm suspecting a better solution to this problem might exist.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative trick for function-like macros is to put redundant parentheses around the declarator in the definition:

```
int (function)(int i) {
    ...
}
```

This prevents the function-like macro from matching and expanding, but has no effect on the definition.

Comment: Note that for at least some function-like macros, you can ensure the consistency of the macro and the function by writing: `int (function)(int i) { return function(i); }` — the parentheses around the name stop that being macro-expanded, and the absence of the parentheses around the name mean that the macro is expanded in the return statement.  Of course, if there is no return value, you omit the `return` keyword  — `void (alternative)(int i, double d) { alternative(i, d); }`.  This technique won't work for all macros, but it will work for many function-like macros.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes, it can be handy to mask a function by a macro of same name.

Macro-like wrapper functions, like

```
static inline int actual_function(int i)
{
    /* extra stuff */
    return function(i);
}
```

are a better option at compile time, because of the Principle of Least Surprise. (As in, you surprise the developers, they do stupid stuff. So the fewer surprises, the fewer stupid mistakes they might do.)

Unfortunately, that does not help with the name change.  I personally don't care, because the rename is just one quick `find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec sed -e 's|\bOLDNAME\b|NEWNAME|g' -i '{}' ';'` away anyway.

---

For dynamically linked symbols, we can wrap or *interpose* them with our own, at runtime.  This is highly OS- and toolchain-specific.

In Linux, there are two options: using the dynamic linker facilities ([`dlsym()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)), or the `--wrap` linker option.  It only works with dynamically linked symbols, but normally, at least the standard library is linked dynamically.

Simply put, if you wanted to replace say the dynamically linked `malloc()` with your own function, you could use

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void *(*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (!real_malloc)
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    /* extra stuff */
    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

If you want to do the above in a thread-safe manner, it gets a bit more complicated. (I use `__atomic_load_n()` etc., so it's just a few lines more code.)

The easier way is to tell GCC to do the symbol magic for us, by supplying it with option `-Wl,-wrap,malloc` when compiling and linking the binary. Then,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *__real_malloc(size_t);

void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    /* extra stuff */
    return __real_malloc(size);
}
```

This time, the interposing/wrapping is done at the symbol table level.